# Django output form errors as table rows in {{ form.as_table }}

Tags: django, django-templates, django-forms

I really find the form output shortcuts such as `as_table` really handy. However, displaying errors while using those methods seems a little counterintuitive to me. When I use the `as_table` format, I would like my field specific errors to be displayed in accordance to table formatting. I can manually piece my forms together like so:

```
<table>
{% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
<tr><td>{{ error }}</td></tr>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}

{% if form.username.errors %}
{% for error in form.username.errors %}
<tr><td>{{ error }}</td></tr>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
<tr><th><label for="id_username">Name:</label></th><td>{{ form.username }}</td></td>

{% if form.password.errors %}
{% for error in form.password.errors %}
<tr><td>{{ error }}</td></tr>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
<tr><th><label for="id_password">Password:</label>/th><td>{{ form.password }}</td></td>
```

But what I want to know is that if there a simpler way to do this? Maybe something I missed in the docs? Or perhaps a different method any of you employ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[**`How errors are displayed`**](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#how-errors-are-displayed) and [**customizing the error list format**](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#customizing-the-error-list-format) show what the default error field output is and how to customize it.

I have been using a [**`reusable template`**](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/?from=olddocs#reusable-form-templates) in my projects recently, which has been working well for me.

table_form.html:

```
<table>
{% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
    <tr><td>{{ error }}</td></tr>
{% endfor %}

{% for field in form %}
    {% for error in form.username.errors %}
    <tr><td>{{ error }}</td></tr>
    {% endfor %}
    <tr><th>{{ field.label_tag }}:</th><td>{{ field }}</td></td>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

template.html:

```
<form>
    {% include 'table_form.html' %}
</form>
```

multiple forms work too, e.g. view with context including form1 and form2:

template.html:

```
<form>
    {% include 'table_form.html with form=form1 %}
</form>

<form>
    {% include 'table_form.html with form=form2 %}
</form>
```

**edit:**

Here is the [**`as_table`**](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/forms/forms.py#L210) method as defined in the BaseForm class:

```
210     def as_table(self):
211         "Returns this form rendered as HTML <tr>s -- excluding the <table></table>."
212         return self._html_output(
213             normal_row = u'<tr%(html_class_attr)s><th>%(label)s</th><td>%(errors)s%(field)s%(help_text)s</td></tr>',
214             error_row = u'<tr><td colspan="2">%s</td></tr>',
215             row_ender = u'</td></tr>',
216             help_text_html = u'<br /><span class="helptext">%s</span>',
217             errors_on_separate_row = False)
```

overriding this method in your form will allow you to change the rendering when you use {{ form.as_table }}

Comment: nice, I like the template idea.

Comment: Although, I have a question about the custom error list class. Can I set my custom list as the default inside my form class definition itself? Or do I have no choice but to put it in the constructor in every view I use a form?

Comment: you might want to look at the [source](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/forms/forms.py). error_class is an attribute of Form inherited from BaseForm. You can override error class when you write your form. You also  can override the as_table method.