# django-registration, django.contrib.auth login and user "is active" flag

Tags: django, authentication, django-registration

I'm using django 1.1. the docs
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/auth/#topics-auth
on the is_active flag it says

> This doesn’t control whether or not
>   the user can log in. Nothing in the
>   authentication path checks the
>   is_active flag, so if you want to
>   reject a login based on is_active
>   being False, it is up to you to check
>   that in your own login view. However,
>   permission checking using the methods
>   like has_perm() does check this flag
>   and will always return False for
>   inactive users.

I'm using django-registration (latest 0.8 alpha) and using all the default backends. The entire premise of django-registration is based on the is_active flag. i.e. it only gets set after user has activated. However, I can see that when a user logs in it is using django.contrib.auth.views.login. i can see this from the code in auth_urls.py.

When a user registers, but hasn't activated yet, I want a message to be displayed that says something along the lines of "You have not activated your account"

Currently the default behaviour is the form's error message says, "user name and password do not match"

I'm also using the login decorator in my views

```
@login_required
```

My questions are:

**EDIT:** Thanks James and Henry. I don't think i've been very good at describing my questions. I've redone this.

1. the django documentation says that is_active is not used as a determinant when logging a user in. This is quite clearly **NOT** the case. Try it yourself. I can't figure out where this happens in the code. Does anybody know? As far as i can see, it doesn't happen in django-registration nor in django.contrib.auth.
2. In order to display the error message i've described above, what would be the best way for me to go about this? Please bear in mind i'm using django-registration and so a lot of the plumbing is done already. i'd rather not modify this or rewrite everything. if possible, i'm looking for an.... "elegant" solution.

Thanks in advance

with respect to Q1,

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to everyone who pondered this question.
In the end i noticed some html code in the default template i hadn't noticed before.

```
{% if form.errors %}
<div class="error">
<p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

Felt kind of stupid after seeing this. I had copied code from another project and just assumed the errors were being dynamically generated instead of being hardcoded.

so then i started investigating

```
forms.errors
```

and found

```
forms.non_field_errors
```

and trying to figure out how to style the output (because by default the stupid thing outputs it inside html ul tags) found this:

[Django output form errors as table rows in {{ form.as_table }}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682694/django-output-form-errors-as-table-rows-in-form-as-table)

Thanks chands (as answer became obvious from his question)

One comment. Documentation on this (at least for 1.1) is **terrible**.
Why this isn't more explicit in offical django docs is beyond me. seems like a pretty basic thing one would want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is in the django-registration.

See the info on line 132 of https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/src/tip/docs/quickstart.rst

It says that it will not allow non-active users to login.

**UPDATE**

You could write your own backend or use the simple backend and add a new property on your profile model called `activated`. This would be a fair amount of work.

As for where it is, I assume it is in `django.contrib.auth.views.login`. Not having spent much time looking through it i think you could fairly easily copy it and make your own. (if it is indeed the issue)

You would then need to replace it in the auth_urls.py file for the login url.

**EDIT**

I just went to docs 1.2 to check differences

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_active 
You will see that it says the form does test it. So either it always did but it wasn't decsribed properly or you've updated to 1.2 and forgotten/not known.

Comment: @James_Khoury thanks James, after spending more time with code, i'm sure this must be checked in django.contrib.auth (and not in django-registration) any idea where? the line of code you point me to is just a comment describing what i'm already observing. Also, any ideas on how to accomplish that specialized error message? thanks.

Comment: @w-- My Apologies. Updated my answer.

Comment: @w-- Just found a peice of information in the docs that should help.

Comment: @James_Khoury thanks. apparently am running 1.1.1... maybe in that patch they changed this? anyway still don't know where in the code it is checked, but figured out how to get proper error message. thanks.

Comment: @w-- https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/tags/releases/1.1.1/django/contrib/auth/forms.py line 82. This is the form used to log in the user. Here is where it Checks to see if they are active. I can probably cook up a quick explanation how you would override this if you want.